# Asymmetric Normal Distribution

Tags: probability

and thank you for reading my problem!

I would like a distribution that

- can have positive and negative values
- is close to normal but skewed.
- I want to set a value for $\alpha_3$ and estimate parameters from
  that restriction.

I have already seen similar question  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189223/asymmetric-normal-probability-distribution), and tried Azzalini's skew-normal distribution. But, $\alpha_3$ for any Azzalini's function is in $\left<-1,1\right>$ and I have larger ones.

I am thinking of using $Gamma$, but this isn't what I wanted....

If you have any suggestions, I would be very grateful :)

Comment: Have you considered mixtures of normal distributions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try $X \sim \mathcal{N}(m_1,\sigma_1)$,  $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(m_2,\sigma_2)$ with $corr(X,Y)=\rho$

Pick $\alpha \in [0,1]$, and we define

$$Z=\alpha e^{X}+(1-\alpha)Y+\mu$$, where $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$

You can start by assuming $X=Y$,  $\mu =0$, $\rho=0$.

The motivation behind this choice is that you have two well-known distributions:

1. $\alpha=1$ and $Z$ is lognormal.
2. $\alpha=0$ and $Z$ is normal.

You can also shift the lognormal distribution using $\mu<0$ to allow negative numbers.

Comment: this seems to be it. Thank you!